# login_enqueue_scripts changes are not reflecting

Tags: wp-admin, login, wp-enqueue-style, wp-login-form

I tried adding a custom CSS for my wp-login page and login forms within my website using the login_enqueue_scripts hook.

My issue is that my changes don't initially reflect on the front end. But the changes showed up the next day when I left it overnight. Why is this delay happening with this hook? Does it require a server restart to start showing the new style changes?

Following is the code I am using in my functions.php, as per [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form).

```
function wpb_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #login h1 a, .login h1 a 
        {            
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/site-logo.png);
        width:300px;
        background-size: 300px auto;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        #login {
        border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
        background: #fff;
        }
        .login form {
            border: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        input#wp-submit {
            font-size: clamp(100%,5vw,101%);
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: #e6e6e6;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            line-height: 1;

            border: 1px px solid;
            border-color:darkgrey;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        input#wp-submit:hover {
            transform: scale(1.1);
            color: #333333;
            transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
            background-color: inherit;
            z-index: 2; 
            width:1.1;
        }

    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_login_logo' );

function wpb_login_logo_url() {
return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'wpb_login_logo_url' );

function wpb_login_logo_url_title() {
return 'New Site';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'wpb_login_logo_url_title');
```

**Edit: Turns out my issue was the LiteSpeed cache plugin. It got resolved as soon as I purged the cache. I am disabling the cache for the development server for now.** ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out my issue was the LiteSpeed cache plugin. It got resolved as soon as I purged the cache. I am disabling the cache for the development server for now. ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, one of my first rules of dev work is "cache nothing".

Comment: Thank you. I will keep it in mind going forward.